# How to execute a chmod in Android - API 8?

Tags: android, linux, media-player, chmod

I have a problem running my application which plays mp3, on Android 2.3.
These mp3 are downloaded from a remote server to /data/data/com.my.package.name/, and the default file permissions are -rw-------.

Unlike on post HONEYCOMB devices (According to my tests), media player refuses to read mp3 if their file permissions are not -rw-rw-rw-.

I obviously verified that if I set files permissions to 666 with the adb shell, then the media player successfully read it.

So, after some researches on the net, I tried to implement the following code, just after writing the file:

```
String chmodString = "chmod 666 " + getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() +"/" + fileName;
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, new File("/system/bin/"));
OutputStream osChgPerms = sh.getOutputStream();
try {
    osChgPerms.write((chmodString).getBytes("ASCII"));
    osChgPerms.flush();
    osChgPerms.close();
    sh.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.d("2ndGuide", "InterruptedException." + e);
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.d("2ndGuide", "IO Exception." + e);
}
```

This code is executed in a fragment but I don't think that changes anything.

Unfortunately, if this code works on post HONEYCOMB devices, where it's not useful,

```
osChgPerms.write((chmodString).getBytes("ASCII"));
```

Throws an `IOException: broken pipe on Android 2.3`, where I really need it.

In fact, I don't really know if the problem comes from the chmod or from the way to execute it.

Any solution to get it working or, to get the media player working on pre HONEYCOMB without changing file permissions?

Comment: There's no reason to use 'su' for this since the files are already owned by your user.  Use the setReadable(true, false) (and if you insist, writable, though that seems unecessary) methods of the File class.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That is in Android API 9+

Comment: Yes Chris, you are right, "su" shouldn't be necessary but as Jared say, it's not possible to use setReadable()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very good question, I ran in this problem a while back!

**Using Java + Android(User must have chmod):**

Folders:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 " + FOLDERNAME);
```

Files:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + FILENAME);
```

Problem: What if they do not have the "chmod" binary? You must download and include it in your application or assets.

**Using Android NDK + JNI(User does not need chmod but needs compiled ndk libs):**

```
/**
 * Change file permissions. Eg. chmod 777 FILE.
 * @param e Java environment.
 * @param c Java class.
 * @param file Path to file.
 * @param mode Permissions for the file.
 */
static jint executeCommand(JNIEnv *e, jclass __attribute__((__unused__))c, jstring file, jstring mode) {
    return (chmod(e->GetStringUTFChars(file, 0), strtol(e->GetStringUTFChars(mode, 0), 0, 8)));
}
```

Problem: Make sure to compile NDK with APP_ABI := all for all devices

**For Java(7+) + Android API 9+(User does not need chmod or libs):**

```
/**
 * Change files to "0777"
 * @param path Path to file
 */
public static void changeFilePermission(final String path) {
    final File file = new File(path);
    file.setReadable(true, false);
    file.setExecutable(true, false);
    file.setWritable(true, false);
}
```

Problem: Your minSDK must be 9!

Comment: arghhh! Why I didn't think to execute the chmod like that! That perfectly works! Thanks a lot Jared

Answer (score 0):

Turning your problem around, you are really asking how can I give Media Player access to data my application provides?

You have chosen to pass it as a file, and thus want to know how to make that file publicly readable.

The alternative solution is to pass the data to the Media Player via a ContentProvider, so that it doesn't need direct access to your data.  Look at `FileProvider` for how to wrap a file up in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an interesting and simple solution for changing permissions of a file in Android system. Just put code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 <path to file>");
```

in a UiAutomator test case. And run that uiautomator test case at your target machine!

Reference: http://android-lihao.blogspot.com/2015/08/modify-permissions-of-files-in-android.html